# Return type of Exception StackTrace

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hi I am writing C# codes from legacy VB Codes, I have a function:

```
Public Shared Sub logError(ByVal ex As Exception, ByVal additionalInfo As String) 
    Dim messagestr As String
    If ex.StackTrace.Length > 0 Then
        For Each stackTrace As String In ex.StackTrace
             messagestr &= stackTrace
        Next
    End If
```

I converted the for loop as:

```
foreach (string stackTrace in ex.StackTrace)
{
      messagestr += stackTrace;
}
```

There is an error message under 'foreach': "Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'.

It's quite weird as I read the StackTrace from MSDN that it returns a string. So I don't know why there is a for loop in the legacy VB codes. Also, I don't where the 'char' comes from.

I think I am complete lost in this area. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2):

The return type of `ex.StackTrace` is a `string`. The object that you will get by iterating over a `string` is `char` not another `string`. So you `foreach` loop must be:

```
foreach (char stackTrace in ex.StackTrace)
{

}
```

Or simply append stack trace to your string:

```
messagestr += ex.StackTrace;
```

If you want to get all function calls separately use this code to split your string into lines:

```
var stackLines = ex.StackTrace.Split('\n')
```

Comment: The part that may be confusing is that VB allows you to use inappropriate types (i.e., 'String' where 'Char' is correct) and sorts it out regardless - perhaps the original VB code used Option Strict Off.

Answer (score 1):

> According to the documentation [StackTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) Gets a string representation
>   of the immediate frames on the call stack.

So when you iterate a string which will actually iterate through its characters, this is happening in your case.

> Where as in VB it Represents a stack trace, which is an [ordered
>   collection of one or more stack frames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx). so when you iterate it
>   iterates through the frames

Comment: First, why do you think StackTrace *class* is specific to VB? Second, to obtain an instance of that *class*, one has to literally instantiate that class, like `Dim trace As New StackTrace`; accessing StackTrace *property* of an Exception class instance will get you a String though, be it C#, VB or whatever other .NET language.

Answer (score 1):

StackTrace is string property of Exception, so if you loop through its member using foreach, its member should be character data type (char). You could simply convert to

```
If (ex.StackTrace.Length > 0) 
{
    messagestr += ex.StackTrace;
}
```